# Could NOT find Boost - python3 components missing

Tags: boost, cmake

When trying to compile `cv_bridge` in ROS2 cmake `find_package` does not find `boost-python3` package.

Follow error ensues:

```
--- stderr: cv_bridge
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.17.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:164 (message):
  Could NOT find Boost (missing: python3) (found version "1.72.0")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.17.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:445 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.17.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2145 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:32 (find_package)


---
Failed   <<< cv_bridge  [ Exited with code 1 ]
```

What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

Making sure CMake uses the built-in Boost CMake files instead of the Boost-installed one fixes the issue:

`colcon build --symlink-install --cmake-args ' -DBoost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE:BOOL=0'`

Add the CMake argument `-D Boost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE:BOOL=0`

As described and referenced from here https://www.forum.freecadweb.org/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=39301 :

> This tells cmake to not use the cmake-config files included in boost directly. Instead config files from cmake are used like for the previous boost versions.

Comment: CMake itself does not provide Boost config files, it provides the FindBoost.cmake module. You might add a link to the FindBoost module documentation https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBoost.html.